# Can't encode in mp3 asunder

Tags: mp3, encoding, cd-ripping

When I try to rip CD's from Asunder and automatically encode in mp3, I get the following error:

```
'lame' was not found in your path.  Asunder requires it to create MP3 files. All MP3 functionality is disabled.
```

What's going on, and how can I fix it?  I tried installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras` as suggested on some forums, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out the problem was *very* simple, so simple I missed it.  I'm including the answer here in hopes that it will help someone.

It turns out the program `lame`, which is used for encoding mp3's by asunder, wasn't installed.  All I had to do was:

```
sudo apt install lame
```

...and that was it!

Note that the recommended method for encoding mp3 is to rip in wav and reconvert to mp3 by an application that uses a different back-end plugin such as Sound Juicer, since lame does not produce high quality mp3's.

Comment: lame has the ability to output 320k (CBR)  mp3s as its maximum bitrate plus more rational settings for VBR encoding. It should just be a matter of altering the encoding settings within Asunder to get great quality mp3s?